# Why is VcXsrv necessary to run GUI app in Linux Docker container on window host?

Tags: windows, docker, user-interface, containers

I've tried to run various applications that require a display in my Linux Docker container. The solution is evidently to share the display on your host machine. The steps to sharing your display always involve configuring a "server" using VcXsrv (or Xming).

What is VcXsrv? The summary on [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) is a bit lacking and the [definition](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/v/vcxsrv.htm#:%7E:text=VcXsrv%20is%20an%20open%2Dsource,for%20the%20X%20Window%20System.) I did find only provided a very high level understanding.

Moreover, why is VcXsrv necessary to run GUI app in Linux Docker container on window host?

Comment: Evidently I'm fairly new to systems and networking. If there are some resources to get started that would be much appreciated. There is so much information and I honestly don't know where to start.

Comment: Docker doesn't have 'GUI's as such. You can't just spin up a docker instance and get a GUI. However, Linux's windowing software (called "X server") is *extremely* good at networked GUIs. That's where you run the OS on one computer and log into it from another computer. Then whem you virtualize a docker instance, your host can connect to it in just the same manner.

It just so happens that there are only two X clients for windows: VcXsrv and Xming.

Comment: I see, thanks a bunch!